# ksqldb Session window generate magic null row

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Today i test Windows in SQL queries and got strange behavior with **Session window**. I create new stream, new session table, and insert **1 row** but in topic see **2 rows** per 1 insert (1 with value null \  , see screenshot). What is problem ?  Other options **Hopping window** and **Tumbling window** dont generate "magic null" row.

create stream:

```
CREATE STREAM MOVIE_TICKET_SALES2 (title VARCHAR, c INT)
    WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='movie-ticket-sales2',
          PARTITIONS=1,
         VALUE_FORMAT='json');
```

create table with session:

```
  create table table_ses60sec2 as select title, count(*) from  MOVIE_TICKET_SALES2 window session (60 second) group by title;
```

insert:

```
 insert into MOVIE_TICKET_SALES2 values ('s', 1);
 insert into MOVIE_TICKET_SALES2 values ('s', 1);
 insert into MOVIE_TICKET_SALES2 values ('s', 1);
```

and select by `print` and `select`:

```
print  TABLE_SES60SEC2;
```

[image]

```
 select * from TABLE_ses60SEC2 emit changes;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The null value is showing that - for the session window around the unix timestamp shown in the key, there was no session result

Notice the keys are not the same, so it's not a duplicate event / faulty output